# Webservice response as HTML instead of SOAP message

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I am working on a wso2 scenario in which I send a SOAP message to a webservice and then receive and manipulate the answer. For this purpose I have TWO Webservices. One is placed in a test environment (1) and the another is the live one (2).

I have no access to the webservice code, I'm just a user.

The problem is:

Via **SOAPUI**

- I'm able to use the service from Webservices (1) and (2). No error, everything works fine.

Via **WSO2**

- I'm able to use the service from webservice (1) but when I point to the webservice (2) I get a HTML 403 Forbidden response instead of a SOAP/XML message.

Am I missing something or this could be a misconfiguration of the webservice?

Following my in/out requests:

[image]

Sequence:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="pricing" trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <smooks config-key="smooks-csv.xml">
        <input type="text"/>
        <output type="xml"/>
    </smooks>
    <iterate expression="//product" id="iterateXML" sequential="true"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
        <target>
            <sequence>
                <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                    <format>
                        <xyz xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                            <safeKey>$6</safeKey>
                            <storeId>$5</storeId>
                            <articleId>$1</articleId>
                            <barcode/>
                            <sku>$2</sku>
                            <price>$3</price>
                            <discount>$4</discount>
                        </xyz>
                    </format>
                    <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//articleId"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//sku"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//price"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//discount"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//storeId"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//key"/>
                    </args>
                </payloadFactory>
                <in>
                    <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://tempuri.org/xyz"/>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint>
                            <recipientlist>
                                <endpoint key="PS_PRICING"/>
                                <endpoint key="fileSave"/>
                            </recipientlist>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                    <drop/>
                </in>
                <out>
                    <send/>
                </out>
                <log level="full" separator=";">
                    <property expression="*" name="ResponsePriceUpdate"/>
                </log>
            </sequence>
        </target>
    </iterate>
</sequence>
```

**UPDATE:**

After testing using TCPMon and TCPTrace I got the following:

Via SOAPUi

- If I send the message SOAPUi -> Live Webservice - **Works fine!** (Picture a)
- If I send the message SOAPUi -> TCPMon/TCPTrace -> Live Webservice - **403 Forbidden!** (Picture b)

It doesn't make sense at all to me. I'm running out of ideas.

(a)

[image]

(b)

[image]

Comment: You can use tcpmon and compare request/response SOAP messages when you use SOAPUI and when you use WSO2 ESB. Maybe you can found the differences and fix...

Comment: The most important stuff is missing in the screenshot (returned html body from server).

Comment: @AydinK. You can see the begining of the html body in the screenshot. I guess that the most important thing (header) is visbile.

Comment: Can you copy the entire server response?

Comment: it's a classic HTML 403 page. Nothing special.

Comment: Can you paste the raw http content from soapUI case? (There is a tab "raw" in the request window). Maybe the soapUI project includes a http basic auth login?

Comment: Thank you @AydinK. The question was answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the people who has found this question relevant:

The problem was in the **server-side**. Server was rejecting some "unknown" sources of incoming traffic.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe add `?wsdl` as postfix to the url: `http://sample.com/webservice.asmx?wsdl`

Comment: It didn't work. Same response. When I send to the test webservice, I do not use ?wsdl either. Thank you for your time!